# Handlebars @index when accessing other objects elements

Tags: templates, template-engine, handlebars.js

I am trying to access another arrays fields with the same index as an array I'm iterating over.

```
{{#each array}}
    {{ otherArray.{{@index}}.myField }}
{{/each}}
```

Is the following possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookup helper did the job:

```
{{#each array}}
    {{#with (lookup ../otherArray @index)}}
        {{myField}}
    {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```